# Different paths for dev vs production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a domain where I'm hosting multiple MVC projects.  I have the virtual directories set so that it's `domain.com/project1`and `domain.com/project2`.  However, on local the projects are just `localhost:xxxx` so the pathing for any ajax or endpoints in the MVC controllers are different on production vs development.  Since I'm using angular routing for both dev would be something like `/Content/Views/home.html` on dev but on live it should be something like `/project1/Content/Views/home.html`.

Is there a good way to do this?  I'm definitely to doing this kind of hosting so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would not be better to create subdomains ? Like following: dev.project1.domain.com ?

Comment: @rahpuser Yes, perhaps that is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a virtual path in visual studio to match your production environment.

Under Project -> ProjectName Properties You'll see the web tab and then the virtual path field.  Here you can input /project1/ so that during debugging your dev environment will match production.